# Create the largest possible number from input - implementation issue with cout

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, vector, numbers

I am trying to implement an algorithm that will take a set of numbers and output the largest possible number (without breaking up the individual numbers). So in an example like this where I give 4 numbers:

4

43 12 3 91

The output would be 
91-43-3-12 or 9143312.

My attempt is below.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::vector;  
using std::string;

bool compare (int x, int y) {
  std::cout << "in func \n";
  string a = std::to_string(x);
  string b = std::to_string(y);
  std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
  std::cout << std::stoi(a.substr(0, 1)) << " " << std::stoi(b.substr(0, 1)) << "\n" ; 
  if (std::stoi(a.substr(0, 1)) < std::stoi(b.substr(0, 1))) { 
    std::cout.flush(); 
    std::cout << "if \n"; 
    return true;
  }
  else { 
    std::cout.flush(); 
    std::cout <<"else \n"; 
    return false;
  } 
}
string largest_number(vector<string> a) {
std::stringstream ret;

while (a.size() > 0) {
  int maxNumber =-1; 
  int index = -1; 
  std::cout << "going into for " << a.size() << "\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    if (! compare (stoi(a[i]), maxNumber ) ) { //stoi(a[i]) >= maxNumber) {
      maxNumber = stoi(a[i]);
      std::cout << maxNumber << " " << i << "\n";
      index = i;
    } 
    std::cout << "here \n";
  }
  ret << maxNumber;
  a.erase(a.begin() + index);
}
string result;
ret >> result;
return result;
}

int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<string> a(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    std::cin >> a[i];
  }
  std::cout << largest_number(a);
 }
```

I do not understand what is wrong with my `compare` function. When I run it, say with this input:

```
$ g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++14 largest_number.cpp -lm -o largest1
$ ./largest1.exe
4
4 23 1 45
going into for 4
in func
4 -1
```

It doesnt print the `cout` statements in the conditional `if` or `else`. How could this be possible? I even tried flushing. However, if I take the entire conditional out, put a `cout` statement and the return true or something, then it runs the program in entirety (although this is not the expected output).

I do not mind harsh criticism. What am I doing wrong here? Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am trying to increase my understanding of algorithms by taking online coursera courses, but I ALWAYS get stuck and discouraged in algorithm implementation issues. I do not know what I am missing to fix this...

Comment: atleast one issue in the code is the use of `substr(0, 1)` - seems like that will break things for negative values

Comment: The flaw in the logic becomes very obvious once you consider the simplest case of only two numbers in the set. Let's say: 47 and 48. It is obvious that `48` will be the right answer from `compare()`, since picking it will end up producing the largest final number. However, your `compare()` will always return `false`, no matter which one of the parameters is 47, and which one is 48, because it compares only the first digit of each number. It is rather obvious that the return value from `compare()` must depend on which one of `x` and `y` is 47, which one is 48.

Comment: @tinkertime it wont consider the "-1" as one character? I hadn't considered that..

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, I will try to loop through the string and compare each number, disregarding negative numbers all together. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not as easy as this. Consider comparing two numbers: 94 and 947. Which one you must pick depends upon whether there are ***any other*** numbers in your list of numbers that start with 8. If there are, you have to pick 94, because you'll end up with a number that begins with "948...". If there aren't any, and the remaining numbers start with 6 or fewer, you have to pick 947, because that'll produce the largest number. If there are any remaining numbers that start with 7, you will have to figure out further. This is not as simple as you think.

Comment: This is a rather complicated problem. However, this problem has nothing to do with C++, whatsoever. It's an algorithm problem. Once you figure out what the correct algorithm is, the C++ implementation should be trivial.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Just to be sure when you said this: "Which one you must pick depends upon whether there are any other numbers in your list of numbers that start with 8." you meant the third digit of another number, say 9483 and not a whole number starting with 8?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Wait, sorry, where did that answer go?? I was still looking into it! I had to finish making dinner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement

```
std::cout << std::stoi(a.substr(0, 1)) << " " << std::stoi(b.substr(0, 1)) << "\n" ;
```

when b is equal to `-1` the expression `b.substr(0, 1)`  is equal to an object of type `std::string` that contains one character `'-'` that is the minus sign.

If to apply the standard function `std::stoi` to such a string then an exception will be thrown.

Consider the following code snippet

```
std::string s("-");

try
{
    std::stoi(s);
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Its output will be

```
invalid stoi argument
```

It seems what you need is just to sort the strings. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v { "4", "23", "1", "45" };

        auto cmp = [](const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
        {
            std::string::size_type i = 0, m = a.size();
            std::string::size_type j = 0, n = b.size();
            int result;

            do
            {
                if (m < n)
                {
                    result = a.compare(i, m, b, j, m);
                    j += m;
                    n -= m;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = a.compare(i, n, b, j, n);
                    i += n;
                    m -= n;
                }
            } while (result == 0 && m && n);

            return 0 < result;
        };


    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);

    for (const auto &s : v) std::cout << s;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program will be

```
454231
```

Or for this set of numbers

```
std::vector<std::string> v{ "43", "12", "3", "91" };
```

the output will be

```
9143312
```

or for one more set of numbers

```
std::vector<std::string> v{ "93", "938" };
```

the output will be

```
93938
```

Comment: I honestly do not understand this code... *nervous laugh*... In particular that return statement.

Comment: @noc_coder You should sort string representations of the numbers. Is it clear? How to sort  them? At first compare their common parts. For example let's there are two numbers "938" and "93". Their common parts are equal. So how to concatenate them? You can concatenate them either kike   938 -93 or 93- 938. It is clear that the second combination is better. Why?  Because the first character after the common part of the first number is less than the initial character of the second number.  Thus 93 is "greater" than 938. This condition is used in the sort function.

Comment: What is meant by "kike 938 -93 or 93- 938". I almost fully understand but it gets shaky there.

Comment: @noc_coder I have included a demonstrative program.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Comment: @noc_coder Take into account that it is better from the beginning to use std::set instead of the vector with the comparison function presented in the answer.